# Two-way data binding Android. Cannot find a getter for <> that accepts parameter type ''

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am building my first android app based on an Udemy Course. It is a gym tracking app. I am trying to add functionality where the user can edit the entries in a recycler view. I am using data binding therefore I assumed that the data was going to be updated automatically. I found out that there is two-way data binding.

I get the error " Cannot find a getter for <> that accepts parameter type " when i add the '=' sign to indicate two-way data binding

this is my editText layout:
'''

```
                android:id="@+id/reps_field"
                android:layout_width="125dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text=" 50 "
                android:inputType="number"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="107dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="629dp"
                app:reps_field="@={workingset}"/>'''
```

Here is my Adapter which i was using to only display the data in a textView

```
@BindingAdapter("reps_field")
fun TextView.setReps(item: Workout?) {
    item?.let {
        text = item.reps.toString()
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the Github repo if that helps
https://github.com/anthony-ruiz/my-workout-tracker

My goal is to be able to save the changes in the data to the database

Comment: I am a bit confused about what the attribute `app:reps_field` is? Do you have a `BindingAdapter` associated with it?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have a BindingAdapter i updated the question. the @BindingAdapter was not showing

Comment: Have you got an `InverseBindingAdapter` as well?

Comment: no, I do not. how could I make one I was looking at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter but I couldn't really figure it out

Comment: I have just posted a full answer along with where you can find more relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your repository, it doesn't seem like you have an `InverseBindingAdapter` set for `reps_field` which needs to be implemented to tell data binding how to retrieve the value from your custom view when it changes. Alongside this you would also need a third binding adapter in order to notify data binding when the value has changed.

There is documentation and a pretty comprehensive example of this process here: [Two-way data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way).

Comment: thank you for looking at my code and pointing me in the right direction. I'll take a look at the resources you linked.